# Is it possible for a EU citizen to stay in Tibet for an extended period of time?

Tags: visas, permits, tibet

Is it possible for a EU citizen to stay in Tibet for an extended period of time? I would like to stay for 1-2 years in a monastery.

Comment: It is not possible. `9. Can I stay in the TAR after my tour is finished?

No, your travel permit is only valid for the duration of your tour. Once your tour is completed, you have to leave. Normally, the travel agency that you use will either book your flight/train ticket departing Lhasa or will ask for you to show your outgoing ticket.` https://www.thelandofsnows.com/faqs-on-travel-in-tibet/ Unless you mean the parts of Tibet outside the Tibet Autonomous Region (TAR). Those areas are covered by regular Chinese visas. The granted duration of stay ranges from 7 to 180 days

Comment: Apparently, it is possible: https://www.quora.com/Can-an-American-citizen-move-out-to-and-live-in-the-Tibet-Autonomous-Region/answer/Andrew-Gwan

Comment: Everything is possible however you are planning to stay in a monastery. That is not work and I think your quora quote confirms such is not possible.